# Can't update SIM contacts using ContentResolver

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentresolver

Im using kotlin to write a function that updates SIM contact phone number, but I'm unable to update it. I always get "Contact not found or update failed". The name, oldPhoneNumber and newPhoneNumber are all correct.

```
 fun updateSimContact(contentResolver: ContentResolver, name: String, oldPhoneNumber: String, newPhoneNumber: String) {
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put("number", newPhoneNumber)
        }

        val selection = "tag=? AND number=?"
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(name,oldPhoneNumber)

        val updatedRows = contentResolver.update(Uri.parse("content://icc/adn"), values, selection, selectionArgs)

        if (updatedRows > 0) {
            // Contact updated successfully
            Log.d("SimContactUpdate", "Updated $updatedRows rows")
        } else {
            // Contact not found or update failed
            Log.d("SimContactUpdate", "Contact not found or update failed")
        }

        contentResolver.notifyChange(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null);
        contentResolver.notifyChange(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null);
        contentResolver.notifyChange(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null);
        contentResolver.notifyChange(Uri.parse("content://icc/adn"), null);

    }
```

What am I missing? Why is it not updating.

I have another code that successfully updates the contact in the device, but after restarting my PHONE original old number that was stored inside the SIM card is loaded.

```
 fun updatePhoneNumber(contentResolver: ContentResolver, contactId: String, oldPhoneNumber: String, newPhoneNumber: String, name:String) {
        val selection =
            "${ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID} = ? AND ${ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE} = ? AND ${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER} = ?"
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(contactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, oldPhoneNumber)

        // Create a ContentValues object to store the new phone number
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, newPhoneNumber)
        }

        // Update the phone number in the Data content URI
        contentResolver.update(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            values,
            selection,
            selectionArgs
        )

        updateSimContact(contentResolver, name, oldPhoneNumber, newPhoneNumber)

    }
```